# Last Day previous Month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Found':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
           'Date':['14/10/2021','19/10/2021','29/10/2021','30/09/2021','20/09/2021','20/10/2021','29/10/2021','15/10/2021','10/09/2021'],
           'LastDayMonth':['29/10/2021','29/10/2021','29/10/2021','30/09/2021','30/09/2021','29/10/2021','29/10/2021','29/10/2021','30/09/2021'],
           'Mark':[1,2,3,4,3,1,2,3,2]

          })
print(df)

    Found     Date   LastDayMonth  Mark
0     A  14/10/2021   29/10/2021     1
1     A  19/10/2021   29/10/2021     2
2     A  29/10/2021   29/10/2021     3
3     A  30/09/2021   30/09/2021     4
4     A  20/09/2021   30/09/2021     3
5     B  20/10/2021   29/10/2021     1
6     B  29/10/2021   29/10/2021     2
7     B  15/10/2021   29/10/2021     3
8     B  10/09/2021   30/09/2021     2
```

based on this dataframe I need to create a new column that is the "Mark" of the last day of the month to form this new column.

that is, I need the value of the 'Mark' column of the last day of the month of each Found

how i did

```
mark_last_day = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x['Date']==x['LastDayMonth'], 1)]


df.merge(mark_last_day[['Found', 'LastDayMonth', 'Mark']],
 how='left',
 on=['Found', 'LastDayMonth'],
 suffixes=('', '_LastDayMonth'))

# Output
Found   Date    LastDayMonth    Mark    Mark_LastDayMonth
0   A   14/10/2021  29/10/2021  1       3
1   A   19/10/2021  29/10/2021  2       3
2   A   29/10/2021  29/10/2021  3       3
3   A   30/09/2021  30/09/2021  4       4
4   A   20/09/2021  30/09/2021  3       4 
5   B   20/10/2021  29/10/2021  1       2
6   B   29/10/2021  29/10/2021  2       2
7   B   15/10/2021  29/10/2021  3       2
```

So far so good but I'm having trouble creating a new column with the Mark_LastDayMonth of the previous month or I need the last day of the current month and the previous month
how do i do it

Ex.

```
    Found   Date    LastDayMonth    Mark    Mark_LastDayMonth    Mark_LastDayPrevious_Month
0     A  14/10/2021   29/10/2021     1       3                     4
1     A  19/10/2021   29/10/2021     2       3                     4
2     A  29/10/2021   29/10/2021     3       3                     4
3     A  30/09/2021   30/09/2021     4       4                     x
4     A  20/09/2021   30/09/2021     3       4                     x
5     B  20/10/2021   29/10/2021     1       2                     1
6     B  29/10/2021   29/10/2021     2       2                     1
7     B  15/10/2021   29/10/2021     3       2                     1
8     B  10/09/2021   30/09/2021     1       1                     x
```

Comment: Could you give the LOGIC of how you are doing it? We just cant tell from the code what you are doing and what you want

Comment: I needed to create a new column With the 'Mark' of the last day of the previous month basically, I get the current month as I showed in the code

Comment: You probably need to convert your string dates to datetime type, then shift the month...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to get the last day of the previous month

```
import datetime

def get_prev_month(date_str):
    format_str = '%d/%m/%Y'
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, format_str)
    first_day_of_this_month = datetime_obj.replace(day=1)
    last_day_of_prev_month = first_day_of_this_month - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return last_day_of_prev_month.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Here is a function to get the mark of any "date" and "found" from your mark_last_day variable

```
def get_mark_of(date_str, found):
    same_date = last_day_mark.Date==date_str
    same_found = last_day_mark.Found == found
    return last_day_mark.where(same_date & same_found).dropna().Mark
```

If you want to add the LastDayPrevMonth column **You don't need to do so unless you want it**

```
df["LastDayPrevMonth"] = df.LastDayMonth.apply(lambda x: get_prev_month(x))
```

And at last the creating the column Mark_LastDayPrevMonth, and setting 0 if there exist no that previous month in the dataset.

```
df["Mark_LastDayPrevMonth"] = df.apply(lambda x: get_mark_of(get_prev_month(x["LastDayMonth"]), x["Found"]), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

[image]

Comment: which is Mark_last_day ? NameError: name 'mark_last_day' is not defined

Comment: mark_last_day is the variable you used to save this df => df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x['Date']==x['LastDayMonth'], 1)]. Its on your code, a line before performing the merge.

Comment: I forgot that detail... but on Found B it's still filling in the number 4, which in this case wouldn't be the number I wanted, it would be either 3 or 0. I'm not able to solve this part

Comment: In that case I have modified the get_mark_of function to consider the attribute "found" as well! Hope everything is set now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the date offset [`MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html)

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

df['LastDayPreviousMonth'] = df['Date'] - MonthEnd()

>>> df[['Date', 'LastDayPreviousMonth']]

        Date LastDayPreviousMonth
0 2021-10-14           2021-09-30
1 2021-10-19           2021-09-30
2 2021-10-29           2021-09-30
3 2021-09-30           2021-08-31
4 2021-09-20           2021-08-31
5 2021-10-20           2021-09-30
6 2021-10-29           2021-09-30
7 2021-10-15           2021-09-30
```

Then do a similarly merge as you did for 'LastDayMonth'.

Does this help you complete the solution?

**Note:** I'm assuming 'Date' and 'LastDayPreviousMonth' are datetime-like. If they aren't you need to convert them first using

```
df[['Date', 'LastDayMonth']] = df[['Date', 'LastDayMonth']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: and from that I create a column with the 'Mark' LastDayPreviousMonth' as ​​in the example

Comment: my problem is not with the month, but with the 'Mark' of the previous month

Comment: @EricAlves sorry, I didn't understand you. Does this solve your issue? Or do you need the complete solution?